# How to create an array of generic objects to be used for a Hash Table?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, hash, declaration

So, I have three classes *HashTest*, *HashTable*, and *HashObject*. The purpose of HashTest is to test the HashTable using three different input sources: Integers, Longs, and Strings.

Depending on which source is specified, I will create a HashTable<Integer|Long|String> object respectively, and begin inserting elements.

In my HashTable class, I must use an array, which will be filled with HashObjects of the given type. My issue arises, where I try to create an array and fill it with generic objects. Originally I had used the following declaration in my HashTable class to try and create an array of HashObjects:

```
private HashObject<G>[] table = (HashObject<G>)new Object[95957];
```

Which will compile, with the warning of unchecked cast, however when I run, I end up getting a ClassCastException thrown. I am not entirely sure why I get this ClassCastException(exact error below), but I know it has something to do with the fact that I declare an array of generic type, and try to cast the object initialization to a generic type. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

**ClassCastException message**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [LHashObject; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [LHashObject; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at HashTable.<init>(HashTable.java:3)
        at HashTest.main(HashTest.java:28)
```

While experimenting I changed the way I create the HashTable object in HashTest, so that the parameter passed to HashTable is <HashObject<Integer|Long|String>>, and then I declare an array of G[] in HashTable and cast to G[] in my initialization:

```
private G[] table = (G[])new Object[95957];
```

This gets rid of my ClassCastException, however, further in my code, I am no longer able to use my HashObject methods, because those methods don't exist for the "undetermined" data type G.

```
((G)table[currIndex]).incrementDuplicates();
```

The above will not work, because the incrementDuplicates() method "is undefined for the type G".

Where I am asking for help is, is there a different way to declare that array, so that I am able to store HashObject's in it, or is there a different way to call HashObjects method, while each element is initialized as Object.

Comment: Note: You should be very cautious of suppressing warnings, but building generic containers (which in Java usually means you need some sort of `Object[]`) is one of the cases where it's necessary. You are responsible for ensuring that your data types are handled consistently; failure to do so can result in hard-to-trace errors in your users' programs.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **you can't**.

`Object` is a `supertype` of `HashObject`, not a subtype, therefore you cannot add an object instantiated as `Object` to an array declared as `HashObject`, no matter what you do.  If you think about it, that `Object` could really be anything, you could be trying to add an `Integer` to a `HashObject` array, which obviously can't work.  You can do the opposite, though.  You can declare the array as an `Object` array, and add instances of `HashObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Few issues here...

```java
private HashObject<G>[] table = (HashObject<G>) new Object[95957];
```

Firstly, you should be casting to `(HashObject<G>[])` instead of `(HashObject<G>)`. Secondly, casting arrays like that doesn't work since the array type is [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). However, what you can do is the following...

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private HashObject<G>[] table = new HashObject[95957];
```

Instantiating the array is fine since `HashObject` in of itself is not generic and the conversion between `HashObject[]` and `HashObject<G>[]` also works since at runtime `HashObject<G>[]` is erased to `HashObject[]`, i.e. they become the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a class cast exception because an array of Object cannot be cast to array of HashObject, just like you couldn't take an instance of Object and cast it to your custom class.

To create an array of HashObject, use `new HashObject[size]`. With generics:

```
HashObject<G>[] table = (HashObject<G>[]) new HashObject<?>[95957];
```